# Android - Best way to use contexts

Tags: android, android-context

I've got a quick question on the best way to handle Android contexts. A lot of things (e.g. Service) require that you pass a context as a parameter. At the present time, I have a public static variable that is set to point to `getApplication()` and I just refer to this throughout my application where a context is required.

Is this ok to do? Or is there a better method to handle this? A lot of my classes don't extend Activity or service and as such, don't have access to `this.getApplication()`.

Everything seems to work ok when I just pass in my static variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this ok to do?

The `Application` object, in some cases, will fail to work. For example, it sucks for UI-related stuff.

Dianne Hackborn, a leading Android engineer, has [stated her regret at `Application` existing](http://www.mentby.com/dianne-hackborn/one-process-two-live-application-objects.html) in the first place.

My general advice is to use `Application` only when you know **specifically** why it is superior to using your `Activity`, `Service`, etc. There are cases when it is the better answer (e.g., binding to services).

> A lot of my classes don't extend Activity or service and as such, dont have access to this.getApplication().

Pass a suitable `Context` as a parameter, as the Android SDK does.

Comment: But *what* is a "suitable" Context? I guess I simply just don't get what a context is used for. I'm not using them for anything except for the mere fact of passing them as parameters to methods that require them. For example, my AlarmBroadcastReceiver (That listens for Intents broadcast by AlarmManager) calls your WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork, that requires a context. What should I send here? (ATM, I'm just sending my public static variable that is mapped to getApplication)

Comment: @jtnire: "But what is a "suitable" Context?" -- if your method is called by an `Activity`, pass the `Activity`. If your method is called by a `Service`, pass the `Service`. If your method is called by a `BroadcastReceiver`, pass the `Context` that is passed as the first parameter to your `onReceive()` method. If your method is called by a `ContentProvider`, call `getContext()` on the `ContentProvider` to get a `Context` to use. That's 99.9% of the cases right there.

Comment: Interesting, those points seem *very* helpful indeed! Just out of interest, what context is sent as the first argument to onReceive of a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @jtnire: "what context is sent as the first argument to onReceive of a BroadcastReceiver?" -- it's a generic `Context`. We should not be making any assumptions about whether it actually is the `Application` or something else, as the implementation may change in the future.

Comment: what about my classes that don't extend anything, yet call methods that require a context? Is using my public static variable to getApplication() ok in this case? An example in my case is my AlarmHandler class, that has static methods for other classes to use to set an Alarm. Due to the samentics of my code, I need my AlarmHandler to be static

Comment: @jtnire: "Is using my public static variable to getApplication() ok in this case?" -- I wouldn't, but it's a free country. "Due to the samentics of my code, I need my AlarmHandler to be static" -- um, OK. Then pass a `Context` into the methods that `AlarmHandler` exposes, and pass those along to the Android SDK methods that require them.

Comment: Sorry, I have another question, when you call sendWakefulWork with the context that is passed in as the first argument of a broadcast receiver, does that mean that the ensuing WakefulIntentService will run in the same context as the BroadcastReceiver? And subsequently, if I pass in the respective WakefulIntentService to methods called by the WakefulIntentService, does that mean that following methods are run also in the context of the orignal broadcast receiver?

Comment: @jtnire: "does that mean that the ensuing WakefulIntentService will run in the same context as the BroadcastReceiver?" -- no. You are reading too much into the noun "context".

Answer (score 0):

> At the present time, I have a public static variable that is set to
> point to getApplication() and I just refer to this throughout my
> application where a context is required.
>
> Is this ok to do?

No.

A context applies to the context in which it was obtained. That is, an activity has context for that activity, a service has context for the service, and so on. Now, a lot of folks do what you are doing, and as you observe, it seems to work. That doesn't mean it will continue to work or that it's good design. If that was the proper pattern, Android would have been designed with Context.INSTANCE that is available statically.

An activity, service, and application are contexts (isA). Receivers are passed a context to their `onHandlerIntent()` method. For all other classes you write, just get used to constructing them with a context. Out of habit, whenever I create a new class, I automatically add a constructor that accepts a context and add a private field to hold it.

When you need a context in a static method, you should pass it in directly as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Can you please enlighten me on the "passed through" nature of contexts? I.e. 1) What context is passed to a onReceiver of a broadcastreceiver? 2) If you start a IntentService with the context received by a broadcast receiver, does the service run in its own context, or in the context of the one received by the broadcast receiver? Thanks

Comment: i can't answer those questions ... but in short, don't worry about it. just use the context that is available in the "context" which you are running. if you are asking because you are thinking about trying to be smarter than the platform, don't do that :)

Comment: Thanks :) Nope, not trying to be smarter, just that I have it in my head that a "service" should be separate from the BroadcastReceiver that started it (I guess I have threading in my head), and just afraid if sending an intent to the service using the context from the broadcast receiver would have some bad consequences. But perhaps not, if that is the correct thing to do :)